# Python script schedule to run on day 1 of each month at 2:00 am

Tags: python, python-2.7, scheduling

I have a script that runs every 30 minutes but there is a section I just want to run on the first of the month at 2:00 am. I am using `schedule` in Python and I can't figure out how to set it for day 1 of the month.

`month` doesn't seem to be in the defined parameters of `schedule` to do something like `schedule.every().month.at("02:00").do(job2)`

Any suggestions? I am using python 2.7

Simplified code:

```
from safe_schedule import SafeScheduler
import time

def job():
    print "I'm working...",
    return

def scheduler():
    # Schedule every30min routines
    print 'Starting Scheduler'
    scheduler = SafeScheduler()
    scheduler.every(30).minutes.do(job)
    #scheduler.every().month.at("02:00").do(job2)

    while True:
        scheduler.run_pending()
        time.sleep(1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
     scheduler()
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The main contributor of the library discourages this sort of thing, see https://github.com/dbader/schedule/issues/73#issuecomment-167758653.

Yet, if one insists, one can schedule a daily job but run it only if it's the 1st of the month.

```
from datetime import date

from safe_schedule import SafeScheduler


def job2():
    if date.today().day != 1:
        return

    # actual job body


scheduler = SafeScheduler()
scheduler.every().day.at("02:00").do(job2)
```

Another alternative is described in one of the issue comments https://github.com/dbader/schedule/issues/73#issuecomment-356769023.

Comment: I was going for something far more complicated ! Well played :-)

Comment: This is perfect!

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT :**
They mention something about this in many issues of the project but a clean solution doesn't seem to exist yet. Also the whole project doesn't seem to be active anymore so I don't think this feature will be implemented anytime soon.

IMO you need to check manually if the current day is the first day of the month in your job in order to do this.

**ORIGINAL ANSWER (which is wrong):**

I've looked at the documentation and you are right, there isn't any mention of month:
https://schedule.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#schedule.Scheduler

But there is an issue opened on the project that mentions just that:
https://github.com/dbader/schedule/issues/73

You can do this:

```
scheduler.every().day.if(lambda d,t: d.day == 1 and t.hour == 2).do(x)
```

Comment: No, you cannot do it. https://github.com/dbader/schedule/issues/73#issuecomment-226500804 asks `does an if() method exist in order to do this?`

Comment: Oh yes you're correct... Also this lib doesn't seem to be maintained anymore so I don't think it'll be a feature anytime soon...

Answer (score -4):

I didn't see any mention of Windows Task Scheduler, here, but that could definitely work for you, if you are on Windows, of course.

https://www.digitalcitizen.life/how-create-task-basic-task-wizard

[image]